# bash bc is unable to compare numbers

Tags: bash

```
~ # echo "1.2>1.3" | bc
syntax error on line 1, teletype
```

I really have two questions. First I want to confirm that the above error is caused by the fact that whatever version of bc I have is NOT GNU bc.

Second, GNU bc is supposedly installed in my system at ~cs9e-1/bin/arch/sun4u/bc. I added that directory to the beginning of my $PATH

```
PATH=~cs9e-1/bin/arch/sun4u/bc:$PATH
```

and tried the above comparison again. Same error.

I figured maybe I should set PATH=~cs9e-1/bin/arch/sun4u/:$PATH instead of PATH=~cs9e-1/bin/arch/sun4u/bc:$PATH. So I did that and then tried the above comparison again, this time getting a new error message:

```
-bash: /home/ff/cs9e-1/bin/arch/sun4u/bc: Invalid argument
```

I just don't know what's going on here.

Comment: Works for me, `bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: Works for me too with the same version as Ashkan (on ubuntu) and `bc 1.06 Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` on OS X Mountain Lion which are GNU versions.  What version does `bc -v` tell you?  You're correct on the path by the way.  What happens if you try that test when running `bc` in interactive mode?

Comment: Can you please try: `echo "if(1.2>1.3) 1 else 0" | bc` (i.e., putting the comparison into an if)?

Comment: @Tim bc -v just says bc: illegal option -- v. -c and -l are the only valid options.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf that line gives the same error

Comment: It seems it isn't picking up a (new) GNU implementation. Perhaps it's therefore adhering to the POSIX syntax for bc. Did you try just running `bc` by itself and typing in your test instead of echoing it through a pipe?  Alternatively, how about `echo "if ( 1.2>1.3 ) 1" | bc` which should return nothing because comparison fails. If that works, reverse the `>` to `<` and you should get `1` as the result.  `echo "if ( 1.2>1.3 ) 1 else 0" | bc` won't work if it's POSIX syntax by the way.

Comment: That works. Where can I read up on POSIX bc syntax?

Comment: Cool.  I'm guessing you don't have access to the man page for your local install of bc?  Most bc man pages (that I'm familiar with) seem to mention differences to POSIX, e.g.: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?bc+1 and see the paragraph about comparisons in the `DIFFERENCES` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following discussion in the comments, it seems that your system still wasn't using a recent GNU implementation of `bc`.  This meant that you couldn't use any extensions to POSIX-compliant `bc` and using comparisons outside of `if` or `while` statements, or a `for` check, is one of those extensions.  Using:

```
echo "if (1.2>1.3) 1" | bc
```

worked, in that it didn't return anything.  Reversing the comparison to `<` returned `1` as expected.

Note that using an `else` (e.g. `echo "if ( 1.2>1.3 ) 1 else 0" | bc`) is also an extension and not supported by POSIX-standard `bc`.

Most man pages which describe versions of `bc` which go beyond the POSIX standard normally describe the differences pretty well.  For example, http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?bc+1 has a "DIFFERENCES" section.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure of the issue with bc on my Linux machine it returned 0

you could also use awk for calculation

```
echo 1.2 |awk -v val="1.4" '{ if ($0 >= val) { print "bigger"; }else { print "smaller"; } }'
smaller

echo 1.2 |awk -v val="1.1" '{ if ($0 >= val) { print "bigger"; }else { print "smaller"; } }'
bigger
```

Answer (score 0):

change from:

```
PATH=~cs9e-1/bin/arch/sun4u/bc:$PATH
```

to:

```
PATH=/home/ff/cs9e-1/bin/arch/sun4u:$PATH
```

You shouldn't add bc command in PATH . PATH is set the order of searching folders.